# Why is_copy_constructible static assertion on a template argument fails?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor

I tried to make a static assertion on a template parameter, to check/enforce the `Type` to be copy constructible. However the static assertion fails. I fail to understand why, and cannot find any documentation why would it fail on static evaluation.

The instantiated class is copy constructible, however it uses what I believe is called curiously recurring template parameter pattern.

Below is the whole test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;


template<typename Type>
class FunContainer {
//  static_assert(is_copy_constructible<Type>::value, "Type must be copy constructible!"); // <- This fails.
//  bool copyable = is_copy_constructible<Type>::value // <- will make the second assert fail
protected:
  int container_stuff = 0;
public:
  int get_container_stuff() {return container_stuff;};
  void set_container_stuff(int stuff) {container_stuff = stuff;};
  bool is_copyable() {return is_copy_constructible<Type>::value;};
};

class Fun : public FunContainer<Fun> {
public:
  std::string str = "Tastic";
  Fun() = default;
  Fun(const Fun& other_fun) : FunContainer<Fun>(other_fun) {
    copy_internals(other_fun);
  };
  Fun& operator=(const Fun& other_fun){
    FunContainer<Fun>::operator=(other_fun);
    copy_internals(other_fun);
    return *this;
  };
private:
    void copy_internals(const Fun& other_fun) {str = other_fun.str;};
};

static_assert(is_copy_constructible<Fun>::value, "Type must be copy constructible!"); // <- the 2nd assert

int main() {
  Fun fun;
  fun.set_container_stuff(10);
  fun.str = "test";
  Fun tastic(fun);
  cout << tastic.get_container_stuff() << '\n';
  cout << tastic.str << '\n';
  cout << tastic.is_copyable()   << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Result is as expected:

```
10
test
1
```

Which means the 2nd assert passed. So it seems that the `Fun` is not CopyConstructible inside the `FunContainer`. However, the `is_copyable` says it is.

I also tried to change `is_copyable()` method to use a `bool` initialized in-class It makes the second assertion fail. When obstructing assertions are removed the value is of `copyable` gets set to 0;

It seems that only evaluation failing is static copmile-time within the base class.

**Q1** Why is compile-time check `false` and "run-time" `true`? Does it fail because the class (`Fun`) is not fully instantiated/defined at the check time?

**Q2** Is this expected? (That the static evaluation of is_copy_constructible gives result than different "run-time" one).

**Q3** Is there a way to make a compile-time assertion that would check if class is CopyConstructible with such a design?

Tested on clang 3.2-11, gcc 4.8.2 and ideone default c++11 compiler.

Comment: Can you make a shorter test case and ask only one question?

Comment: @KerrekSB I think the questions 1 and 2 are highly related I can drop the 3rd one, as it asks about the work around. It is hard to make it shorter and demonstrate every behaviour. Do you have any suggestion? (I am not sure if operator= is needed, so might cut it out.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Q1** Why is compile-time check false and "run-time" true? Does it fail because the class (Fun) is not fully instantiated/defined at the check time?

Yes. `FunContainer<Fun>` is instantiated before `Fun` is defined, when you use it as `Fun`'s base class.

> **Q2** Is this expected?

Yes.

> **Q3** Is there a way to make a compile-time assertion that would check if class is CopyConstructible with similar design?

Move your static assertion somewhere that gets instantiated at a later time. Inside `FunContainer`'s constructor seems like a good choice to me.

Comment: Thanks advice with moving the assertion into the constructor. I guess the reason the answer to **Q2** is "yes", is because at the place where I put the check, `Fun(const Fun&)` would be illegal to call i.e. `Fun` cannot be copied at the instantiation of `FunContainer` because it is not yet a complete type there, am I right?

Comment: @luk32 Sort of, yes, even though there's hardly any way to actually copy a `Fun` object at that point anyway, because you're not inside a function.

Comment: Well, there must be a reason why it gives `false`, none of the compilers say "It is a bad place to copy object, so the check is pointless/wrong".

Comment: @luk32 Indeed. What I meant was: you won't be able to copy objects at all at that point, but if you do find a way around that (and, for example, manage to copy an `int`), you still wouldn't be able to copy `Fun` objects, for the reason you too gave in your comment.